# Create new rows in custom table with current user Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve id from Users table and insert it in Activity table with another new data

```
  public ActionResult Create( Activity activity, RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
       var user = db.Activities.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == currentUserId);

        ViewData["user"] = currentUserId;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));
            activity = new Activity()
            {
                Name = activity.Name,
                Description = activity.Description,
                Date = activity.Date,
                UserId = (Convert.ToString(user)),

            };


            db.Activities.Add(activity);
            db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(activity);
    }
```

nothing happen with this code ,

Comment: What errors are you getting? var errors = ModelState.SelectMany... it should be above the if (ModelState.IsValid) statement.

Comment: no errors nothing happen

Comment: `nothing happen` says nothing. What did you expect and what *did* happen? Did you debug the code? Is the model valid or is the entire data access block bypassed? `user` is an *activity*, not a user ID, so your code will never store a User ID. `user` can only be retrieved if there's only *on* activity for that user. It will throw if there are more than one, and return `null` if there are no activities. I doubt that's what you want

Comment: do some debugging, make sure that `ModelState.IsValid` is true

Comment: ModelState.IsValid is false I want to insert new data to an activity table based on the current login userid

Comment: Check the models you are passing to the controller and be sure they have data